# Collisions in Processing with jbox2D library?

Tags: box2d, processing, jbox2d

I'm new to Processing, new to JBox2D, and new to Stack Overflow, so any help I could get would be much appreciated!

I'm trying to write a simple program based on Shiffman's JBox2D/Processing tutorials, where you click to create a new ball, then drag and release the mouse to throw it. Balls can collide with one another and a ring of circles ("keys") around the edge of the sketch. Every time you click a ball object is added to an array list.

Everything works fine, until you start clicking rapidly, creating many balls in a short period of time. The best I can explain it is that the sketch seems to "lose its physics"... the balls no longer fall or bounce around, they cling to each other and just hover in the middle of the sketch. I get an error message saying "Could not invoke the "beginContact()" method for some reason" with a long list of errors that starts with "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)...." etc etc etc

Any help would be so very greatly appreciated!!

My code:

```
import shiffman.box2d.*;
import org.jbox2d.common.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.joints.*;
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.*;
import org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.Shape;
import org.jbox2d.common.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.*;
import org.jbox2d.dynamics.contacts.Contact;
import org.jbox2d.callbacks.ContactImpulse;
import org.jbox2d.callbacks.ContactListener;
import org.jbox2d.collision.Manifold;

Box2DProcessing box2d;

Spring spring;
ArrayList<Ball> balls;
ArrayList<Key> keys;

float colors[] = {
  40, 80, 120, 160, 200
};
float border=130;

void setup() {
  frameRate(30);
  colorMode(HSB);
  size(1280, 800);
  smooth();

  box2d = new Box2DProcessing(this);
  box2d.createWorld();
  box2d.setGravity(0, -30);
  box2d.listenForCollisions();

  // Make the ball
  balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
  spring = new Spring();

  //KEY PLACEMENT
  //top row
  float x = 0;
  float y = 0;
  int c = 0; //index of colors array
  float keysSize = 120;
  keys = new ArrayList<Key>();
  for (int i=0; i<11; i++) {
    keys.add(new Key(x, y, keysSize, colors[c]));
    x+=width/7;
    c+=1;
    if (c==colors.length) {c=0;}
  }
  //bottom row
  x = 0;
  y = height;
  for (int i=11; i<20; i++) {
    keys.add(new Key(x, y, keysSize, colors[c]));
    x+=width/7;
    c+=1;
    if (c==colors.length) {c=0;}
  }
  //sides
  x = 0;
  y = keysSize*1.2;
  for (int i=20; i<30; i++) {
    keys.add(new Key(x, y, keysSize, colors[c]));
    if (x==width) {x = 0; y+=keysSize*1.5;}
    else {x+=width;}
    c+=1;
    if (c==colors.length) {c=0;}
  }
} //END SETUP


void draw() {
  background(0);
  box2d.step();

  //DRAW KEYS
  for (int i=keys.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    Key k = keys.get(i);
    k.display();
  }

  //DRAW BALLS
  for (int i=balls.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    Ball b = balls.get(i);
    b.display();
    if (b.done()) {
      balls.remove(i);
    }
  }

  //DRAW SPRINGS
  spring.update(mouseX, mouseY);
  spring.display();
}//END DRAW

void beginContact(Contact cp) {
  // Get both fixtures
  Fixture f1 = cp.getFixtureA();
  Fixture f2 = cp.getFixtureB();
  // Get both bodies
  Body b1 = f1.getBody();
  Body b2 = f2.getBody();

  // Get our objects that reference these bodies
  Object o1 = b1.getUserData();
  Object o2 = b2.getUserData();

  if (o1.getClass() == Ball.class && o2.getClass() == Key.class) {
    Ball b = (Ball) o1;
    Key k = (Key) o2;
    k.hit();
  }
  else if (o2.getClass() == Ball.class && o1.getClass() == Key.class) {
    Ball b = (Ball) o2;
    Key k = (Key) o1;
    k.hit();
  }
  else if (o1.getClass() == Ball.class && o2.getClass() == Ball.class) {
    Ball b = (Ball) o1;
    Ball c = (Ball) o2;
  }
}

void endContact(Contact cp) {
}

void mousePressed() {

  if (mouseX>border && mouseX<width-border && mouseY>border && mouseY<height-border) {
    if (classes[index]=="Ball") {
      balls.add(new Ball(mouseX, mouseY));

      for (int i=balls.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        Ball b = balls.get(i);
        if (b.contains(mouseX, mouseY)) {
          spring.bind(mouseX, mouseY, b);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
  for (int i=balls.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    Ball b = balls.get(i);
    b.hasLaunched = true;
  }
  spring.destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the bodies are spawning inside each other, which is going to cause problems.

You could modify your spawning algorithm so that you only spawn new bodies in empty space, or you could limit how often a new body is created.

Googling "box2d spawning inside body" returns a bunch of promising results.